# xslt to retrieve href value from XML

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

i am new to XSLT, currently i have requirement to extract xref values from the below xml .

need to pick the xref which comes in the tag **< link rel="**next**" href= />**

Note : requirement is to look for <link -> rel="next" and extract href value to store it in variable.

expected results is :

```html
   <properties>
      <code>40000018</code>
      <name>+++ ATZ +++</name>
   </properties>
   <next_page>skiptoken=eyJzdGFydFJvdyI6MTAwMCwiZW5kUm93IjoyMDAwfQ==</next_page>
</results>
```

The below is the xml sample  :

```html
<feed xml:base="https://api12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
   <title type="text">Position</title>
   <id>https://api12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/Position</id>
   <updated>2021-11-05T03:51:45Z</updated>
   <link rel="self" title="Position" href="Position"/>
   <entry>
      <id>https://api12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/Position(code='40000018',effectiveStartDate=datetime'2020-03-16T00:00:00')</id>
      <title type="text"/>
      <updated>2021-11-05T03:51:45Z</updated>
      <author>
         <name/>
      </author>
      <link rel="edit" title="Position" href="Position(code='40000018',effectiveStartDate=datetime'2020-03-16T00:00:00')"/>
      <category term="SFOData.Position" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
      <content type="application/xml">
         <m:properties>
            <d:code>40000018</d:code>
            <d:externalName_defaultValue>+++ ATZ +++</d:externalName_defaultValue>
         </m:properties>
      </content>
   </entry>
   <link rel="next" href="https://api12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/Position?$select=code,externalName_defaultValue&amp;$skiptoken=eyJzdGFydFJvdyI6MTAwMCwiZW5kUm93IjoyMDAwfQ=="/>
</feed>
```

and currently i am using the below xslt and that giving results except the href values.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a d m">
<xsl:template match="/">
<results>
      <xsl:for-each select="//a:entry/a:content">
        <properties>
            <code><xsl:value-of select="./m:properties/d:code"/></code>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="./m:properties/d:externalName_defaultValue"/></name>
        </properties> 
      </xsl:for-each>
</results>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not defined well enough. You say you want to "extract href value" but the expected result shows only *part* of the href value - and we have no rules regarding how to locate the part you want.

The following stylesheet produces the expected result, but it is based on a guess and could fail if the guess is not valid for other examples:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
exclude-result-prefixes="a d m">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/a:feed">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="a:entry/a:content">
            <properties>
                <code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="m:properties/d:code"/>
                </code>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="m:properties/d:externalName_defaultValue"/>
                </name>
            </properties> 
        </xsl:for-each>
        <next_page>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(a:link[@rel='next']/@href, '&amp;$')"/>
        </next_page>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi michael.hor257k , its works fine . Thank you so much your helps and really sorry for confusion in the description.